# Counting points around a point conditional on time values

Tags: qgis, time, count

I want to count the number of points from one layer around each point from a different points layer. The thing is that each point (from both layers) has an "entrance date", so I want to count only those points that have an entry date prior to the one relating to.

For example:

I have a point with an entry date equal to August 2016, and a second layer of 2 points with an entry date equal to July 2016, and 2 points with an entry date equal to December 2016. All of the points are within 100m of the first point.
I want to be able to get the number of points, within 100m radius (in this example), that have an entry date prior to August 2016. In this example, the result would be 2.

Comment: What program are you using? Can you provide some sample attribute  structure?

Comment: This would be pretty easy to do in Postgres/Postgis, using a combination of date/time functions and spatial functions.

Answer (score 2):

An approach using `Virtual Layer`.

**Sample**

I prepared this example:

- point_layer_a: `id_a` (integer) and `entry_a`(date) fields
- point_layer_b: `id_b` (integer) and `entry_b`(date) fields

Green buffer (radius 200m) zones were drawn only for illustration.

[image]

**Virtual Layer**

( `Layer | Add Layer | Add/Edit Virtual Layer` )

[image]

Query is:

```
SELECT id_a, entry_a, count(*)
FROM point_layer_a JOIN point_layer_b
ON (st_distance(point_layer_a.geometry, point_layer_b.geometry) < 200) 
WHERE to_date(entry_a) > to_date(entry_b)
GROUP BY entry_a
```

The output (virtual layer):

[image]

Sorry I am offering an example of date-to-date comparison only, not month-to-month as you prefer.